# OPENCV crash when saving to file trained machine learning data (like SVM or ANN)

Tags: java, android, opencv, save, svm

I have built a simple project in android studio, and included OpenCV in order to train either an SVM (support vector machine) or an ANN (artificial neural network). Everything seems to go well, including data creation, training and inspection of trained data, except for saving. Whenever I save a opencv ml-object (like ann.save(...) or svm.save(...)), android studio crashes.

- SVM -

When I extract supportvectors using the line

```
classifier.getSupportVectors()
```

the numbers seem sain. However, the app crashes when I move past a breakpoint placed at

```
 classifier.save("C:\\foo\\trentsvm.txt");
```

In logCat I dig up the following feedback:

> 07-04 14:36:10.939 25258-25258/com.example.tbrandsa.opencvtest A/libc:
>   Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7f755f53f0 in tid
>   25258 (ndsa.opencvtest)      [ 07-04 14:36:10.942   439:  439 W/]
>   debuggerd: handling request: pid=25258 uid=10227 gid=10227 tid=25258

I get a similar error if i instead try to save an artificial neural network (ANN), see update far below.

I have tried saving the file as XML and txt, and as "C:\trentsvm.*someformat*", and as "trentsvm.*someformat*". I also get the same error in my Eclipse java project. High pain, no gain. Full code is below. Could you help?

PS: I use OpenCv version 3.2.0. and Android Studio 2.3.2

```
// I based this code on stuff i found online. Not sure if all is as important or good.
// Purpose: multilabel classification - digit recognition for android app.

// Create data and labels for a digit recognition algorithm 
int numTargets = 10; // (0-9 => 10 types of labels)
int totalSamples = 100; // Could have been number of images of digits
int totalIndicators = 10; // Could have been number of properites per digit image.
Mat labels = new Mat(totalSamples,1, CvType.CV_16S);
Mat data = new Mat(totalSamples, totalIndicators,CvType.CV_16S);

// Fill with dummy values:
for (int s = 0; s<totalSamples; s++)
{
    int someLabel = s%numTargets;
    labels.put(s,0, (double)someLabel);
    for (int m = 0; m<totalIndicators; m++)
    {
        int someDataValue = (s%numTargets)*totalIndicators + m;
        data.put(s, m, (double)someDataValue);
    }
}
data.convertTo(data,  CvType.CV_32F);
labels.convertTo(labels,  CvType.CV_32S);


SVM classifier = SVM.create();
TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER,100,0.1);
classifier.setKernel(SVM.LINEAR);
classifier.setType(SVM.C_SVC); //We choose here the type CvSVM::C_SVC that can be used for n-class classification (n >= 2).
classifier.setGamma(0.5);
classifier.setNu(0.5);
classifier.setC(1);
classifier.setTermCriteria(criteria);

classifier.train(data, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

// Check how trained SVM predicts the training data
Mat estimates = new Mat(totalSamples, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
classifier.predict(data,  estimates, StatModel.RAW_OUTPUT);

for (int i = 0; i<totalSamples; i++)
{
    double l = labels.get(i, 0)[0];
    double e = estimates.get(i, 0)[0];
    System.out.print("\n fact: "+l+", estimat: "+e);
}
Mat suppV = classifier.getSupportVectors();


try {
    if (classifier.isTrained()){
    // It crashes at the next line!
        classifier.save("C:\\foo\\trentsvm.txt");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

---

Update july 5th: As suggested by ZdaR, I tried the to use an in-phone adress, but it did not solve the problem.

```
String address = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/trentsvm.xml";
// address now has value "storage/emulated/0/trentsvm.xml"
classifier.save(address);
```

In logcat:

> 07-05 14:50:12.420 11743-11743/com.example.tbrandsa.opencv2 A/libc:
>   Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7d517f1990 in tid
>   11743 (brandsa.opencv2)
>
> [ 07-05 14:50:12.424  3134: 3134 W/         ] debuggerd: handling
>   request: pid=11743 uid=10319 gid=10319 tid=11743

---

Update july 6th:
When I run the same script in eclipse and use a debugger (JUnit 4, VM arguments: -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\tbrandsa\Downloads\opencv\build\java\x64;src\test\jniLibs, ) debugging on the pc without device, the caught exception "e" says the following

> cause= Exception,
>   detailMessage= "Unknown Exception" ,
>   stackTrace=> StackTraceElement[0] ,
>   suppressedExeptions= Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList,

---

Update july 13th:
I just tried with an artificial neural network (ANN) too, and it crashes when trying to save.

Error:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x15a57e688000c in tid
>   8507 (brandsa.opencv2)  debuggerd: handling request: pid=8507
>   uid=10319 gid=10319 tid=8507

Code:

```
// Mat data is of size 100*20*CV_32FC1, 
// Mat labels is of size 100*1*CV_32FC1
// layerSizes is of size 3*1*CV_8UC1
int[] hiddenLayers = {10};
Mat layerSizes = new Mat(2 + hiddenLayers.length,1,CvType.CV_8U);
layerSizes.put(0, 0, data.width());
for (int l = 0; l< hiddenLayers.length; l++){
    layerSizes.put(1 + l, 0,hiddenLayers[l]);}
layerSizes.put(1 + hiddenLayers.length, 0,labels.width());

ANN_MLP ann = ANN_MLP.create();
ann.setLayerSizes(layerSizes);
ann.setActivationFunction(ANN_MLP.SIGMOID_SYM);

ann.train(data, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE , labels);
ann.save("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/no.rema.priceagent.test/trentann.xml");
```

Comment: `"C:\\foo\\trentsvm.txt"` seems to be a path in your Windows OS, which wont be valid for android as there exists no directory namely `"C:\\foo..."`. You may use `Environment.getExternalStorage().getPath()` to get the absolute path to your sd card where you could write your trained results.

Comment: Thanks, ZdaR. I tried your tip, but it did not help. Details in the bottom of the newly updated text.